# After upgrading from .net framework to .net 6 my user settings are in a new folder

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, settings

After we upgraded our project from .net framework to .net 6.0 I experienced weird behavior with the user.config file.

We already have an existing user.config file in AppData from previous versions with .net framework. If I now go ahead and do a Settings.Default.Upgrade() the settings are not carried over. It is creating a completely separate folder. This means all the previous settings are lost and you need to reconfigure.

- [SoftwareName].e_Url_[hash]            ---NET Framework
- [SoftwareName]*Url*[hash]               ---NET6.0

I was also able to see that in QuickWatch the settings module references now the .dll instead of the .exe

Comment: There isn't much differences between an exe and a dll.  The exe has a main method which is an entry point when starting from windows.  The dll may or may not have the main entry point.  Some dll can run from windows by double clicking because they have the main entry point.  The project csproj file is text and best way of understanding differences between new and old is to open the csproj with a text editor.  Project settings can be modified to get new project to work like old project.  So what is wrong?  Weird behavior is not a question.    Looks like your target change from Framework to Net.

Comment: Yes my target changed from Framework to Net. Thats the whole point of my question. This should in theory not mean that the user.config is put into a completely separate folder. The topic here is the user.config path change and .Upgrade() not working how its supposed to.

Comment: May the people who designed your project did not following the standard practices,  Nothing wrong with doing things different, just don't expect when you upgrade that your project setting will not require modifications.  Yes, this is a Microsoft issue that Microsoft attempts to do things their way, even though it may not always be right.